# Is it possible to query a publication list in an Enterprise 2.0 account

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, publicationlist

I'm trying to query a publication list to extract the unsubscribes into a data extension. Does anyone have a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [**System Data Views**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5)?

The [**_ListSubscribers**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/data_view_listsubscribers/) view contains that info.

Publication Lists are handled the same way as regular Lists.